# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target - angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm using `ngx-translate` in service. Exactly in this function.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class StartService {

    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }

    load(): Promise<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.context + 'health', null, true)
            .map(res => {
                const response = res.json() as InvioTelematicoBaseModel
                if (response != null && response.error != null && response.error.esito === 0) {
                  ////////
                } else {
                    this.http.restUpAndRunning = false;
                 this.esitoSectionService.setErrorMessage(this.translateService.instant('IMPOSSIBILE_CONTATTARE_I_SERVIZI_REST')); // here I'm using this.translateService.instant
                }
            })
            .toPromise()
            .catch((err: any) => {
                this.http.restUpAndRunning = false;
                Promise.resolve()
            });
    }
}
```

When I added `this.translateService.instant('IMPOSSIBILE_CONTATTARE_I_SERVIZI_REST')` inside  `this.esitoSectionService.setErrorMessage()` I get this error

```
> [at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors 
> [at-loader] ./compiled/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts:286:31  TS2346: Supplied
> parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Have you any idea please, how to use `ngx-translate` in this case?

This is function serErrorMessage:

```
setErrorMessage(message: string) {
    const baseRestResponse = new InvioModel();
    baseRestResponse.error = new ErrorModel();
    baseRestResponse.error.esito = 99
    baseRestResponse.error.error = message;
    this.baseRestResponse.next(baseRestResponse);
}
```

Comment: Does this.esitoSectionService.setErrorMessage expect a parameter?

Comment: @Alexander I added `setErrorMessage ()` function

Comment: @Alexander have you any idea please?

Comment: You might need to debug the issue further, ie log out only `translateService.instant(...)` and see if it's been loaded yet. Might be worthwhile to recompile the app as well, ie ng serve again.

Comment: I fixed it, only I added `?` in `private translateService?: TranslateService`. Thanks guys